# join count mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

How can I write the query, select albums.*, count number of images in images table,
if no images on albums count as zero. One album may has 0 or more images.

The following query result in no rows when the album has no images.

```
SELECT `albums`.*, count(images.id) as num 
FROM (`albums`) 
INNER JOIN `images` ON `images`.`album_id`=`albums`.`id`
```

Comment: Use a left join instead of an inner join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... You need to use a `left join` and a `group by`

```
  SELECT `albums`.*, count(images.id) as num 
  FROM (`albums`) 
  LEFT JOIN `images` ON `images`.`album_id`=`albums`.`id`
  GROUP BY albums.id
```